# How to get All users in web application by setting role as search parameter - asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In my MVC application I am using  membership service . I need a  page to list the users. But there are 1000's of users are in my application. So i don't need to display all of them in one page.

I am planning to give a search option .I mean admin user can search by specifying user role and how many users can show in one page.How can i do this ? Any ideas?

**current code**

Model

```
public MembershipUserCollection Users { get; set; }
```

Controller

```
 model.Users = Membership.GetAllUsers();
```

But i am getting all users in the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to query your role provider:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    string[] usernamesInRole = Roles.GetUsersInRole("some_role");
    ...
}
```